# ngcordova angularjs geolocation google maps (no ionic)

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ngcordova

I would like to learn how to display a Google map with some custom markers using ngcordova angularjs but no ionic framework.

Could you point me to a comprehensive tutorial for beginners (no missing steps) that explains how to do it, please?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several alternatives:

- you can simply use an Angular module such as [ngMap](https://ngmap.github.io/), and in this case you don't need a tutorial but their documentation. There you can find all kind of example.
- you can adopt a Cordova Plugin like [cordova-plugin-googlemaps](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps) which has a specific tutorial in the documentation
- search also here on SO for example: angular-js-and-google-maps

Answer (score 1):

its work in app as well as browser.
1. add google map script in in index.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js">
</script>
```

2. in html side

   < div align = "center" >
      < div id = "map" style = "width:100%;height:200px" > < /div> 
    < /div>

3 in script side

```
var latlng = {
lat: 12.34343,
lng: 34.12313
 };
var map;

 function initMap(latlng) {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: latlng,
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 14,
    dragging: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    draggable: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    keyboardShortcuts: false,
    panControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    disableDefaultUI: false
  });
   var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#F2F2F2',
    strokeOpacity: 0.7,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#0DCCC0',
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
    map: map,
    center: latlng,
    radius: Math.sqrt(5) * 100
   });
 }
```

4. call **initMap(latlng)**

its work fine in my app and browser. and best benefit its design on marker. just like a  Circle.